# Get folder (or sub-files/folders) last modification date and time

Tags: macos, bash

Is it possible to get the modification date and time of a folder?
I know you can use `stat -f "%m" folder`, but it doesn't reflect sub-files/folders changes.

Things that doesn't work:

- `ls -l folder` - doesn't reflect changes inside the folder
- `stat -f "%m" folder` - same as above
- `date -r folder` - same again
- `find foo bar baz -printf` - the `printf` option doesn't exist on my version of find

Versions of things:

- OS: Mac OS X 10.7.1
- Bash: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)

Comment: Try the answers that listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997242/in-linux-terminal-how-do-i-show-the-folders-last-modification-date-taking-its

Comment: None, of them work as the `printf` option is not implemented in `find` in Mac OS X 10.7.1

Comment: Are you looking for the most-recently modified file or directory in a particular directory? How recursive do you want to get?

Comment: I'm more familiar with the GNU/Linux side of things as opposed to BSD flavor.  `find -printf` is often useful, but lacking that maybe you could get by with a `ls -lRt | head -n 1` (`-t` for mtime sort, `-R` for a recursive listing)

Comment: 1) Yup  2) Around 6 levels deep

Comment: @jw03 Yeah but this sorts it first by parent-directory and not only date/time

Comment: @Tyilo yes you are right. `ls` isn't really the best way to go about it anyway.  Maybe something like `find -execdir stat -f '%m %N' \{} \; | sort -nr | head -n 1` to replace `find -printf`.  This example would still need to add null terminators to handle all file names properly but the general idea should work.

Comment: @jw013 didn't see your comment before posting my answer, but we found nearly the same solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution:

```
find . -exec stat -f "%m" \{} \; | sort -n -r | head -1
```

Explanation:

1. the `find` command traverses the current directory (`.`) and for each file encountered executes (`-exec`) the command `stat -f "%m"`. `stat -f "%m"` prints the last modification unix timestamp of the file.
2. `sort -n -r` sorts the output of the `find` command numerically (`-n`) in reverse order (`-r`). This will list the latest modification timestamp first.
3. `head -1` then extracts the first line of the output from `sort`. This is the latest modification unix timestamp of all the files.

Comment: would be good to get some explanation what each part is doing, this command crashed my computer.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Added an explanation. If you're using Linux-based OS and not BSD-based this will probably not work for you.

Comment: This gives wrong information in case someone deletes a file in a folder. Say for example you are trying to maintain an md5 hash for a folder and would like to know when to recompute it. Then this wouldn't work...

Answer (score 7):

You could try 'date -r folder' to give you a date last modified

Comment: `-r seconds
             Print the date and time represented by seconds, where seconds is
             the number of seconds since the Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1,
             1970; see time(3)), and can be specified in decimal, octal, or
             hex.`

Comment: +1 @Tylio but to clarify - "date -r folder +'%s'" - will return the seconds since epoch look at "date --help" for more information

Comment: @ChrisK `-r` means reference file in GNU `date` which seems to be what you are referring to while in BSD `date` (the flavor Mac OS X uses), it behaves as quoted in Tyilo's comment

Answer (score 0):

You could always get it from `ls` :

```
ls -ld mydir | awk -F' '  '{ print $6 " "$7 }'
```

Comment: Doesn't take sub-files into consideration

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sub-files" however on my system new files created in the directory will update the parent directory modification time.

Comment: @JJ not on mine unfortunately

Comment: Odd. I use Ubuntu Linux FWIW.

Comment: im using Lubuntu 13.04 and creating new files in the subfolder does not update the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to clear cache after build . then you can check the age of the last change and delete it like this

```html
sh("find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -mmin +360 -name 'Cache-folder-*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} /bin/rm -rf '{}' || echo 'There is no such folder! Start script execution' ; exit 0")



sh("find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -mtime 0 -name 'Cache-folder-*' -ls -exec rm -r {} \\;")
```