# How to change modified time for folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am taking zip file as input which contains multiple files and folders,I am extracting it and then I want to change the last modified time of each content in zip to some new date and time set by user.

I am using `os.utime()` to change the date and time, but changes get reflected only to the files and not to the folders inside zip.

```
timeInStr = raw_input("Enter the new time =format: dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS -")
timeInDt=datetime.datetime.strptime(timeInStr, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
timeInTS=mktime(timeInDt.timetuple())
epochTime=(datetime.datetime(timeInDt.year, timeInDt.month, timeInDt.day, timeInDt.hour, timeInDt.minute, timeInDt.second)-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
z=zp.ZipFile(inputZipFile,"a",zp.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for files in z.infolist():
    z.extract(files, srcFolderName)
    fileName=files.filename  
    new= fileName.replace('/',os.path.sep)
    correctName= srcFolderName+os.path.sep+new
    print correctName
    if(correctName.endswith(os.path.sep)):
        correc=correctName[:-1]     
        print correc
        os.utime(correc, (timeInTS, timeInTS))
    else:
        os.utime(correctName, (timeInTS, timeInTS))
```

I am using Python 2.7 as platform

Comment: place some code u tried and where u have encountered problem.

Answer (score 4):

Base to the directory permission is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451863/when-does-a-unix-directory-change-its-timestamp) on SO. The directory only changes its timestamp when the directory itself changes for ex: when you create a new file in it. So to update the timestamp of folder you can create a temp file and then delete it. There should be a better way but till you find it you can manage using this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394938/3290955) is the code I used to get past the issue.

As user966588 stated, the directory's timestamp is updating as the directory changes.

In the post I linked, I held onto any directory metadata updates until after my directory was fully-populated in order for the timestamp change to stay.