# List of completely untouched directories

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm currently writing a clean up script and for that i need a list of folder without any changes to subfiles or subdiretories. Right now i have this as a base. (Would like it to be untouched for the last 14 days)

```
find ./* -type f -mtime -14
```

Which will generate a list of any untouched files and directories. The problem is that this one will generate a list where some directories might show up any way because there only been changes to a couple of files within some of the subdirectories.

Does anyone have any idea how to generate a list of completely untouched directories?

cheers!

Comment: You might want to read [this question about what constitutes a modification in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451863/when-does-a-unix-directory-change-its-timestamp). According to this info, your directories whose subdirectories have been changed shouldn't be listed.

Comment: Also you say your command "will generate a list of any untouched files and directories", but since you've added a `-type f` selector to your `find` command I doubt it lists any directory at all.

Comment: Doesn't `-14` mean to find files that have been modified no more than 14 days ago?  Don't you want files that have NOT been modified in the last 14 days?  I think `+14` is what you might want, unless i'm not understanding.

Comment: You need a list of files/dirs that *have* changed, and a list of all. If something has changed, that directory has a change and should be kept, as should its parent tree. If nothing in a directory has changed it can go. This is largely a matter of sorting both lists and walking them in sync, using the changes list as the driver. Am I understanding what you need correctly?